# Javafx: Using Threads to load a GIF as background

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, gif, java-threads

In school I am working on a project using JavaFx. I would like to make it special and use a GIF as background. 
It works and displays my GIF, but it makes my program and GIF run realy slow.

Is there a way to fix this using Threads? 
(I am new to using threads and don't realy know how to use them here).

this is my code for the background:

```
public class WelkomScherm extends StackPane
{


    private final screenControl sCtrl;

public WelkomScherm(screenControl sCtrl) 
{ 

    this.sCtrl = sCtrl;

    //Image backgroundImage = new Image("/img/startBG.gif");
    Image backgroundImage = new Image("/img/Welkom.png");
    ImageView background = new ImageView(backgroundImage);
    background.setFitHeight(height);
    background.setFitWidth(width);       

    ...some buttons and labels...

    this.getChildren().addAll(background,...,...);
}
```

I am also new to working on bigger projects, all tips are welcome!

Comment: How large is your image?

Comment: 1100 x 800, I didn't think it was to big?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? Is hardware acceleration enabled? (You can try running `java -version` if you're unsure of the first, and running your program with `java -Dprism.verbose=true` for the second).

Comment: I am using JDK 8 & hardware accelaration is enabled. For my GIF i used 24 fps because I need it to be smooth.. Is this to much?

Comment: How big is the actual file (in MB)? How many frames in total?

Comment: 5,33MB with 150 frames at 24 fps, I know there are a lot of frames, thats why I thought the best option was using threads

Comment: Have you tried out the constructor allowing you to load the image in the background ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/image/Image.html#Image-java.lang.String-boolean- )?

Comment: I don't realy understand what I need to do in my example.. @fabian

Comment: `new Image("/img/startBG.gif", true)`

Comment: thanks a lot! it does load quicker! but my bg stays white on every screen while loading the GIF, is there no other way to make the gif load more quickly? @fabian

Comment: Keep the image as soon as loaded, make it static or place it in another class. The constructor should  check if the image is already there and use it in case it is. You need to synchronize this, in case the windows come up in parallel.

Comment: I used CSS to load the gif, this is called in the very beginning and keeps the gif loaden for the whole program. Thanks!